# "Equal" sign optional in "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, rfc

Hello in my project built on ASP.NET Core 2.2, I need to implement webhook to handle "notification" from a third-party API.

We deploy it, then we test it but every requests fall in 400 bad request. 
I investigate, then I detect that the body of sent requests (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) contains a "missing" equal sign in the query **&data[subject_name]&data[user_uid]**, ex:

```
webhook_type=create&network_name=test&data[id]=389&data[action_name]=action&data[target_name]=target&data[subject_name]&data[user_uid]=b6643dc6-946b-490a-86b8-eb5c67f82bca&data[type]=Comment
```

data[subject_name] may be null or empty but with this query data[user_uid] is not parsed (default guid) ! Because ASP.NET framework can't correctly parse the query

Image of the [parsed query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0uLY.png)

I propose to the third-party API developers two solutions : 
1. force add "equal" sign when the field is null or empty

```
webhook_type=create&network_name=test&data[id]=389&data[action_name]=action&data[target_name]=target&data[subject_name]=&data[user_uid]=b6643dc6-946b-490a-86b8-eb5c67f82bca&data[type]=Comment
```

2. remove null or empty fields from the query

```
webhook_type=create&network_name=test&data[id]=389&data[action_name]=action&data[target_name]=target&data[user_uid]=b6643dc6-946b-490a-86b8-eb5c67f82bca&data[type]=Comment
```

The answer was: "*no, it's a standard we do not change anything*"

Here the model

```
public class WebHookDto<T> where T : ThirdPartyNotificationDto
{
    [Required]
    [EnumDataType(typeof(WebHookType))]
    [FromForm(Name = "webhook_type")]
    public WebHookType WebHookType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(1)]
    [FromForm(Name = "network_name")]
    public string NetworkName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [FromForm(Name = "data")]
    public T Data { get; set; }
}

public class ThirdPartyNotificationDto
{
    [Required]
    [FromForm(Name = "id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

public class UserNotificationDto : ThirdPartyNotificationDto
{
    [Required]
    [FromForm(Name = "user_uid")]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [FromForm(Name = "action_name")]
    public string ActionName { get; set; }

    [FromForm(Name = "target_name")]
    public string TargetName { get; set; }

    [FromForm(Name = "subject_name")]
    public string SubjectName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EnumDataType(typeof(NotificationTargetType))]
    [FromForm(Name = "type")]
    public NotificationTargetType TargetType { get; set; }
}
```

Here the controller/action

```
[HttpPost("user")]
public AcceptedResult UserNotificationListener([FromForm]WebHookDto<UserNotificationDto> request)
{
    // some code that validate the query or throw exception
}
```

Here the full query

```
POST /api/v1/notification/user HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:44300
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

webhook_type=create&network_name=test&data[id]=389&data[action_name]=action&data[target_name]=target&data[subject_name]&data[user_uid]=b6643dc6-946b-490a-86b8-eb5c67f82bca&data[type]=Comment
```

My questions are:

**The optional "equal" sign is it a standard like third-party developers said ?**

**What is the best way to fix this issue, if third-party developers stuck on their position ?**

**Do you think I need to open an issue on ASP.NET Core github for this ?**

**Edit #1 : Here the issue on [asp.net core github] (https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/12381)**

Comment: That's a bug in the query string parser. The API client isn't necessarily wrong to specify the value that way, although ASP.NET (not Core) will parse that as `null = "data[target_name]"` if I remember correctly. I think that's wrong, too.

Comment: Hello, I know it works on Spring Boot but I don't found any RFC which precise that the "equal" sign is optional 
Thank for your help

Comment: Some time ago, I was writing a parser as an alternative to the one in System.Web for applications that can't depend on System.Web; I was trying to emulate the behavior when I saw that little nightmare. It might be undefined behavior but certainly not what one would expect. In my singular opinion, for whatever it's worth, yes, I think you should file a bug. If nothing else, the discussion that ensues should be quite illuminating.

Comment: @odinnou , from RFC 3986, section 3.4 https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.4 , "The query component is indicated by the first question
   mark ("?") character and terminated by a number sign ("#")" [...] "However, as query components
   are often used to carry identifying information in the form of
   "key=value" pairs and one frequently", The use of an equal sign to establish a "key value" data representation in a query string is completely optional (although it is a widely agreed upon convention).

Comment: @Gaboik1 hello, I find this quote in the RFC but it's not clearly write that the 'equal' sign is optional right ? And maybe URL and x-www-form-urlencoded can be different is several ways (like not start by '?')

Comment: @odinnou
>it's not clearly write that the 'equal' sign is optional

 Most importantly, it doesn't say anywhere that it is required. Like I said, it is a very widely agreed upon convention to format a query string like '?key1=val1&key2=val2' but strictly speaking, your third party service developer is right, the '=' is not required.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this issue, with the use of a middleware :

```
app.UseMiddleware<RemoveInvalidFormKeysMiddleware>();
app.UseMvc();
```

This middleware will rewrite "invalid" keys in Request.Forms

```
public class RemoveInvalidFormKeysMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public RemoveInvalidFormKeysMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        Dictionary<string, StringValues> validForm = new Dictionary<string, StringValues>();

        foreach (var form in context.Request.Form)
        {
            if (!form.Key.Contains('&'))
            {
                validForm.Add(form.Key, form.Value);
                continue;
            }

            string key = form.Key.Substring(form.Key.LastIndexOf('&') + 1);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key))
            {
                validForm.Add(key, form.Value);
            }
        }

        context.Request.Form = new FormCollection(validForm);

        await next(context);
    }
}
```

Then we can keep the rest of the logic without change anything else

```
[HttpPost("user")]
public AcceptedResult UserNotificationListener([FromForm]WebHookDto<UserNotificationDto> request)
{
    // some code that validate the query or throw exception
}
```

Hope it helps, Rémi